Eagerly loading related objects with Entity Framework Core
I'm using Entity Framework Core in .NET Core, but I'm struggling to get related objects to eagerly load.
Here is my relevant code:
public class User : SchemaObject, IUser
{
     public long? UserID { get; set; }
     public Session Session { get; }
}

public class Session : SchemaObject, ISession
{
    public long? SessionID { get; set; }
    public long? UserID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Session)
            .WithOne(e => e.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Session>(e => e.UserID)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Navigation(u => u.Session)
            .AutoInclude();
    }
}

Query:
user = db.Users
         .Include(u => u.Session)
         .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Session.SessionID == result.requestObj.Session.ID);

I've tried both using .Include() in the query as well as .AutoInclude() in OnModelCreating() but neither have worked.
Doing a check like
if (user.Session == null)

will always succeed. The only way I got it to work was doing
db.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.Session).Load();

after the initial query, but, from my knowledge, this will make another round trip to the db and I don't want that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Add setter to property Session - public Session Session { get; set; }. EF Core cannot assign value.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried that and it did not work =(

Why PK's are nullable? User (long? UserID) and Sesssion(long? SessionID). Also it can be problem with conventions UserId, not UserID . Define Primary keys explicitly.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv PK's are nullable because they are null until the object is saved. Defining Primary Keys explicitly did not work either.

EF treats 0 as not assigned PK.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I did not know that, neat. I updated the Ids to be non nullable and it still didn't work. On a side note, I am also noticing that tracking of entities doesn't seem to be automatic either. When I retrieve a user using a db context, update the user, and then save using the same db context, it thinks its adding a new User and will fail (due to an obvious PK constraint). I have to manually attach the User to the context to get around this. Don't know if this could somehow be related?

Usually EF Core users has problem when using context.Update method. I don't know how do you manipulate with your entities.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I don't use context.Update. Just retrieve the entity using a query, update a property on the entity, and then call context.SaveChanges, like illustrated here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/

I was facing other Entity Framework issues and the comment from @StevePy here fixed all of them
